# Pi4 OVERHEATING and damage micro sd

Tags: pi-4, sd-card, boot-issues, troubleshooting, failure

i have a pi4 2gb wich overheat and damage the microsd as soon as i boot it.
After booting pi4 it show this message and the microsd start to burn. when i pull it out from pi and insert inside an adapter to a computer, it says microsd is useless and unreadble. also micro sd keeps on burning, even when plugged to mac adapter.
any advice can be really useful to me.
thank u
[image: load sreen]

Comment: It really sounds like the SD card might be faulty. Can you try another one?

Comment: A. It sounds like the SD was either defective to begin with, or is damaged now - I wouldn't put it into any electronics you don't want damaged. B. It is quite likely the PI is now also damaged. What you describer sounds a lot like a short-circuit in the card. If you have a multimeter - you could try using on cards contacts in short-location mode. Also, what brand is the card, and how sure are you it is not a counterfeit?

Comment: your post is like `my car is on fire, so i moved it to another garage, but it is on fire there too`

Comment: @jstola - I've heard of cascades of dead PCs where a faulty video card was tried in several other machines to 'see if it worked' in them. It didn't, and neither did they afterwards.